# How can i see if my JSON contains a certain value and then compare it?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, json.net

```
var Name = "Resources.myjson.json";
var NameJSON = new System.IO.StreamReader(typeof(Strings).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(Name)).ReadToEnd();
var ParsedBrandJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TheInfo>(NameJSON);
await JsonCS.LoadJson(ParsedBrandJSON);
```

And on the page:

```
static public class TheInfoJSON
{
    static public TheInfo Data { get; set; }
    static public async Task LoadJson(Data JSON)
    {
        Data = JSON;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TheInfo
{
   public List<TheName> TheName { get; set; } = new List<TheName>(); 
}
```

My json:

```
{
"TheInfo":[
    {  
       "TheName": ["Martin", "Jonas", "Alex", "Oscar"]
    }
  ]
}
```

When i now try to compare how can i see if my JSON contains a certain object and then store that as a single `TheName`? Is it possible to do it in the same cast?

```
var TheNameDataFromOtherPage = OtherPage.TheName; //Here i gather the name from another page that i will compare with the JSON

//Wrong syntax
bool DoTheyMatch = TheNameDataFromOtherPage == TheInfoJSON.Data.TheName.Contains("Alex");
```

This is now wrong syntax because i cant compare the value to a bool. How can i get out the data i find and then instead of having `TheInfoJSON.Data.TheName.Contains("Alex");` as a bool, back to a single value of `TheName` containing "Alex" so I can create a bool out of the two values to see if the JSON has it or not.

I tried to add something along the lines like this after the contains(): `as TheInfo.TheName` but that isnt the correct syntax either.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool DoTheyMatch = TheInfoJSON.Data.TheName.Contains(TheNameDataFromOtherPage);
```